# Wrong distro and logo in GNOME control center

Tags: unity, gnome, gnome-control-center

I want to edit the logo in `gnome-control-center details`, but I can't find the location where the image is stored. It also represents the wrong version (screenshot). Because I'm building my own distro, I want to replace it with a custom image.

Ubuntu GNOME was used as a basis and I left `unity-control-center` and it's dependencies intact. I did an upgrade to GNOME 3.16.

I checked `/usr/share/gnome-control-center` and `/usr/share/unity-control-center`, but the logo can't be found there. Also tried to search it in nautilus with various search terms.

Is is possible that it's linked to cache or saved files in `/etc/skel` or `~/.config` ?

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have to download the source:

```
apt-get source gnome-control-center and gnome-control-center-data
```

Go into the `source/panel` directory. 
Replace `UbuntuLogo.png` and check inside config files inside that directory. Don't forget `info.gresource.xml` because if you miss one reference to the correct new icon it won't work. Two other locations within sources requiring renaming: `debian/rules` and `debian/patches/56_use_ubuntu_info_branding.patch`.

Bottom line source only solution. Easy to do however:

Uncomment out sources in `/etc/apt/sources.list`, and then:

```
apt-get install checkinstall
apt-get build-dep gnome-control-center-data gnome-control-center
./configure # (inside main directory)
make
sudo checkinstall # (answer questions script asks)
```

Answer (score 0):

The logo file for Gnome Control Center (at least for v3.6.3) is located at `/usr/share/gnome-control-center/ui/UbuntuLogo.png` and part of the `gnome-control-center-data` package. You should be able to change it to something else with that info.